# Where and how to initialize the images that a program will use, prioritizing memory?

Tags: python, tkinter

Given the nature of the question, the most appropriate and least complex way of managing the images that the program itself will use (icons, backgrounds, logos, etc.) is sought. This question does not require code, but rather a schematic that illustrates the structure of the problem, which I present later. An important point is also that the methodology or solution satisfies the need to open the program with its images on any PC without any problem. I hope to have your help or suggestions, all help is appreciated as I am just starting to program interfaces, very grateful. Thanks.

```py
import os   # os.path.join(), os.listdir()
import sys  # sys.argv
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class A1(Tk):
    def __init__(self, folder):
        super().__init__(folder)

class A2(Toplevel):
class A3(Frame):
class A4(Frame):
class A5(Frame):
class A6(Frame):
class A7(Frame):
class A8(Frame):

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        folder = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        folder = os.getcwd()

    root = A1(folder)
    root .mainloop()
```

Comment: Unless you are creating thousands of images, optimization isn't going to be necessary.

Comment: @BryanOakley So is it ok if I pass a list of hundreds of initialized images in the class that inherits from Tk to the other classes? . Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: try it and see what happens.

Comment: @MarinoFerry if you are simply passing a list that references some objects in memory, you are not copying those objects, you only pass the reference. Even if you copy, that only copies the list itself and not the objects, the copied list still contains references to previous objects. Only if you deepcopied the list, there would be made copies of the objects themselves. Otherwise if you simply give the other classes a reference to a list that references other large objects, you are not really using any memory